# Error getting foreign key data on entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm new in MVC2 and Entity Framework and I tried get a list of products with the respective category name, but it's returned me the error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I have a table `Product` with a foreign key `Category`.

I'm using MVC2 and Entity Framework 4.0.

```
public class Repository 
{       
        public IQueryable<Produto> ListAllProducts()
        {
            return entities.Produtos;
        } 
}

public class AdminProdutoController : Controller  
{   

    TudoDeMassinhaRepository repository = new TudoDeMassinhaRepository();    

    public ActionResult Index()     
    {       
          var produtos = repository.ListAllProducts().ToList();
          return View(produtos);    
    }  
}
```

code in view where the error is generated: `<%: item.CatProduto.cat_produto_nome%>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only selecting the products - you're **not** currently including the categories. This means: you'll get back your product objects, but any **related** objects they refer to are **not** loaded automatically - that's why the `.CatProduto` property will be NULL and thus you're getting the error.

You need to explicitly specify which additional entities you want to have loaded - something like:

```
public IQueryable<Produto> ListAllProductsWithCategories()
{
        return entities.Produtos.Include("CatProduto");
}
```

This way, you should get back your `Produto` objects, and their `CatProduto` property should have been loaded and populated, too.

So if you change your index method to be:

```
public ActionResult Index()     
{       
      var produtos = repository.ListAllProductsWithCategories().ToList();
      return View(produtos);    
}
```

it should work.

Comment: Hi marc_s thaks for your response, but I still getting the same message. Any Idea??????

Comment: Hi, @marc_s I solved the problem, was on database. The database was with corrupted data and there was a product with id_category that wasn't on category table.  Thanks a lot.